# Unit Testing Angular Service that uses $timeout with Jasmine's Mock Clock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a function inside one of my angular services that I'd like to be called repeatedly at a regular interval.  I'd like to do this using $timeout.  It looks something like this:

```
var interval = 1000; // Or something

var _tick = function () {
     $timeout(function () {
        doStuff();
        _tick();
    }, interval);
};

_tick();
```

I'm stumped on how to unit test this with Jasmine at the moment - How do I do this?  If I use `$timeout.flush()` then the function calls occur indefinitely.  If I use Jasmine's mock clock, `$timeout` seems to be unaffected.  Basically if I can get this working, I should be good to go:

```
describe("ANGULAR Manually ticking the Jasmine Mock Clock", function() {
    var timerCallback, $timeout;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy('timerCallback');
        jasmine.Clock.useMock();
    }));

    it("causes a timeout to be called synchronously", function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            timerCallback();
        }, 100);
        expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        jasmine.Clock.tick(101);
        expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

These two variations work, but do not help me:

```
describe("Manually ticking the Jasmine Mock Clock", function() {
    var timerCallback;

    beforeEach(function() {
        timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy('timerCallback');
        jasmine.Clock.useMock();
    });

    it("causes a timeout to be called synchronously", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            timerCallback();
        }, 100);
        expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        jasmine.Clock.tick(101);
        expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

describe("ANGULAR Manually flushing $timeout", function() {
    var timerCallback, $timeout;

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        timerCallback = jasmine.createSpy('timerCallback');
    }));

    it("causes a timeout to be called synchronously", function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            timerCallback();
        }, 100);
        expect(timerCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(timerCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try injecting `$rootScope` and calling `$rootScope.$apply()` after pushing the clock forward.

Answer (score 52):

Do not make your test Async by using Jasmine's clock. Instead, use `$timeout.flush()` to synchronously maintain the flow of the test. It may be a bit tricky to setup, but once you get it then your tests will be faster and more controlled.

Here's an example of a test that does it using this approach:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ngAnimate/animateSpec.js#L618

Comment: Your answer solves the problem, as well as reiterates an important rule of thumb: Unit tests should always be synchronous

Answer (score 46):

@matsko's answer led me down the right path. I thought I'd post my "complete" solution to make it simpler to find the answer.

## The thing to test

```
angular.module("app").service("MyService", function() {
    return {
        methodThatHasTimeoutAndReturnsAPromise: function($q, $timeout) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve(5);
            }, 2000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

## The test

```
describe("MyService", function() {
    var target,
        $timeout;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$timeout_, MyService) {
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        target = MyService;
    }));
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        done();
    });
    it("equals 5", function(done) {
        target.methodThatHasTimeoutAndReturnsAPromise().then(function(value) {
            expect(value).toBe(5);
            done();
        });
        $timeout.flush();
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't the `done()` in the "equals 5" test redundant?  `$timeout.flush()` will synchronously call all of the pending events registered in $timeout, which will cause the promise to resolve, which will immediately call `expect()`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. Might be worth a test, though.

Comment: @AviCherry Without the `done` callback parameter, the code will trigger the flush but then immediately consider the test passed, because it does not know that an asynchronous call was triggered. With `done` , you make sure that the test will not be completed until `done` is called. An `expect` will not finish a test. You can have multiple expectations in a test. 

Also, if you provide the `done` callback but you never execute it, your test will fail because Jasmine will throw something like `execution took too long`, because the test will never be completed. Can't remember the exact feedback.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's right. So, pay attention to the `beforeEach` function which calls `done()` _first_. That's the key that tells Jasmine an async call is coming. So when `$timeout.flush()` is called, it's pending until the `done()` is called after you're finished `expect`-ing. Good note @Justus!